# Windows 10 Night light on all screens

Tags: windows-10, nightlight

I use my Lenovo notebook on a Thunderbolt docking station and Windows 10's Night light only works on the main screen (the Notebook's screen).

Is there anything I can do to enable the Night light mode for all screens?

Comment: Are you sure it’s actually a Thunderbolt connection? Or even just USB-C with DisplayPort? Because it very much sounds like it’s actually just USB with a DisplayLink adapter/chip.

Answer (score 1):

This is normally caused by issues with a Hub or the connection itself. You can try to connect the monitor directly to your Notebook or use a different connector.

If this doesn't do the trick, I can recommend [flux](https://justgetflux.com/) which does the same but runs in the background as an application. You are able to customize the settings even a bit more regarding the time of day or adjust the colour.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too. What worked for me was dis-connecting and re-connecting my monitor. ‍♀️